# how to create empty koalas df

Tags: python, spark-koalas

I am trying to create empty Koalas DataFrame using the following command

```
df = ks.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C']))
```

But I am getting the following error

`ValueError: can not infer schema from empty or null dataset`

I tried following command too, but found the similar error

```
df = ks.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You **CANNOT** create an empty Koalas DataFrame because `PySpark` tries to infer the type from the given data by default. In the consequence, `PySpark` cannot infer the data type for a DataFrame if there is no data in the DataFrame or the column.

To easily understand, Koalas DataFrame doesn't have the data type to allow `None` type like Pandas (`object` type).

So, if you still want an empty DataFrame, I would recommend you to initialize a DataFrame with `Pandas` and just convert it to `Koalas` DataFrame when you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ks.DataFrame({}, index=list('abc')).empty
```

[reference](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.empty.html)